# JQuery click function works only once

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to create a dynamic src attribute for a PDF viewer on my page. It works perfectly. It fires up a click event every time I click on a row on my data table and get the second child value and use it as the pdf viewer's scr attribute. I use attr function to change the src attribute of the pdf viewer. When I click once it works and show the corresponding pdf on the viewer. But when I click second time on another row. PDF is not being changed on the viewer which is supposed to be. I also use show function to make viewer visible after I click the row. 
Thanks in advance guys.

Here is my code;

```
   $("#last tr").on('click', function() {
    var fgr = $(this).children('td').eq(1).html();

    $("#pdfviewer").show();

    $('#pdfviewer').attr('src','pdf/'+fgr+'.pdf');
```

});

This is my html code that I have created the div element in.

```
<div class="row">
                <div id="pdfviewer" class="col" style="display:none">
                  <embed id="pdf" src="" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">


   </div>
```

Comment: We need to see some html related to this issue.  And just to confirm, there is only one element on the page with an id of `pdfviewer`, yes?

Comment: Yes there only one pdfviewer element on the page.

Comment: Check the console if some error is being thrown, this mostly happens if some error is encountered inside the event callback.

Comment: No there nothing thrown on the console right now. I basically alert value that I am getting from click event and it works perfectly. So it is not the problem apparently. But probably there is some issue sending this value into the pdfviewer src attribute I guess. After once I click and get the viewer and pdf, with nedt click I get nothing, pdf doesn’t renew itself. Do I have to reload the pdfviewer to see the new pdf or something ?

Comment: Only the outer div has closing tag. Try adding closing tag to other elements.